# SyntaxError: The requested module 'sourcemap-codec' is expected to be of type CommonJS when I'm trying to compile my angular project

Tags: json, angular

```
SyntaxError: The requested module 'sourcemap-codec' is expected to be of type CommonJS, which does not support named exports. CommonJS modules can be imported by importing the default export.
<e> For example:
<e> import pkg from 'sourcemap-codec';
<e> const { decode, encode } = pkg;
<e>     at ModuleJob._instantiate (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:98:21)
<e>     at async ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:137:5)
<e>     at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:165:24)
```

I tried downgrading angular cli nothing worked